# How to know a Windows Store App has terminated in C# or VB?

Tags: c#, vb.net, uwp, windows-10-universal, kill-process

I know Windows Store Apps are executed in isolated mode (a sandbox). Hence I start an App (e.g. Microsoft Photos) by using `IApplicationActivationManager.ActivateForFile`, the image provided gets displayed and the return value of the function gives me the process Id (e.g. 6544 for a process named ‘ApplicationFrameHost’ and a main window title of ‘Photos’. But when I register a handler to the `.Exited()` event of the according process I won’t get informed when I close the App (unlike to a Win32/64 application like notepad.exe).

Unpleasantly furthermore I receive the same Process Id for the next image to be displayed as well – both images are held by the same process now. And all images displayed subsequently return the very same process Id as well... and my `.Exited`-Handler is still not called, neither in case I close only one of now several running Photo-Apps nor after finally I have closed all of them.

Since I could not yield notification about the process with my image was closed I thought of looking up if it is still on display. I investigated all propertied of Process including the `ProcessThreadCollection` and `ProcessStartInfo` but found nothing to identify my displayed images. And even when I investigate the MainWindowsTitles by looping through the open windows (with `User32.EnumWindows()` or `WindowsInterop.GetRootWindowsOfProcess(p.Id)` this does not give me more then fife times “Photos” for fife displayed images – alas without the filenames of the images displayed!

Any hint to get around that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use AppDiagnosticInfoWatcher to monitor the state of an app and get notifications when it changes:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.appdiagnosticinfowatcher

Comment: Wick MSFT: I did not know about that an will give it a try - txt a lot!